# Закруглить изображения, показываемые с Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, imageview

Я пытаюсь сделать приложение, которое показывает изображения  в recycleView с сервера Firebase **(показывает, но не скачивает из в память устройства)**. Углы у изображений должны быть закруглены, высота и ширина 160dp (то-есть фото должно полностью занимать imageView). Как на картинке 1. Это я сделала, до того как загружала изображения с сервера( но это не работало с очень широкими картинками).

После, я сделала, так что фото загружаются с сервера, но они отображаются не той формы что мне надо (картинка 2).

Как сделать так, чтобы фото с сервера подгонялись под размер и форму (обрезалось лишнее пространство и сглаживались углы как на 1 картинке)?
[image: картинка 1].

adapter:

```
listRef  = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("sleep");
            photoImView = holder.photoImageView;
            
                    listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                        @Override
    
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                        for(StorageReference file:listResult.getItems()){
                            file.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    imagelist.add(uri.toString());
                                    Log.e("Itemvalue",uri.toString());
                                }
                            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(imagelist.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())).into(holder.photoImageView);
        
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

category_layout.xml

сюда я вставляю изображения для `recyclewview`. Файл с `recyclewview` наверное скидывать не надо?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_image_view"
            layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ImageViewStyle"
            />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

styles
с помощью этого кода я закругляю углы у фото

```
    <style name="ImageViewStyle" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily"> rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize"> 20dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: у вас прогрузилась только одна картинка... Судя по описанию вам нужно попробовать для свойства android:scaleType поменять значение fitCenter на centerCrop, например.

Comment: там где стоит всего одна и таже картинка, это я так сделала для примера(это было до того как я загружала фото с сервера).

Comment: спасибо большое, работает

Comment: Есть ещё 1 способ. Для Glide есть такая замечательная библиотека: https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations  . Там можно делать картинку с круглыми краями, делать её размытой менять контрастность и многое другое. Может кому-то понадобится